# DateTimePicker: Disable all past dates and time selection

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I basically want my `Jquery:dateTimePicker` to allow only future dates -  that said if the current dateTime is: 30th August 2016, 10:20am then I would want to select a time greater than 10:20am - not **less than 10:20am only for 30th August 2016** but should allow for **any time for all other future dates**.

Is this possible with a simple configuration change?

Any help appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Which datetimepicker do you use? There's mostly an option for `startDate` when you initialize it.

Comment: jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.3.4 @http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ - I'm concerned about the time. It should be greater than Aug 30th 10:20am - how do I freeze the time for only a particular day ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minDate: 0` to allow future dates only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this to disable past date and time

add this css and js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js,
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrapdatetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrapdatetimepicker.js,
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrapdatetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css

```
$(function () {     
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
             format : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            minDate: moment().add(0, 'h')
                });
```

or

```
$(function () {     
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
             format : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            minDate: moment().add(1, 'm')
                });

        });


            });
```

Comment: @Sithara Suresh you need to add moment.js in your application

Comment: I have an empty calendar now ...with no dates and time!

Comment: @Sithara Suresh  i have added the css/ js please add this js and css it will.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {     
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
         format : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        minDate: moment().add(0, 'h'),enabledHours: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,17]
      });

 });
```

Please check this example and modify `minDate: moment().add(1, 'h')` to`minDate: moment().add(0, 'h')` in the example like i modified for you and use moment.js
And please enable the hours as you want.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/5u694sat/5/)